# Missing shutdown entries in wtmp despite graceful reboots

Tags: shutdown, reboot, systemctl, last, wtmp

Linux system with kernel **4.14.76** and last from util-linux **2.35.1**.

I am using `last -x reboot shutdown` to detect abrupt shutdowns and power loss. To my understanding, a clean reboot should show as a pair of **shutdown** and **reboot** entries in wtmp. This is supported by e.g. [this article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2642741#last). An ungraceful shutdown or powerless can be inferred thorough sequential **reboot** entries with no **shutdown** in between.

However, I am finding that there isn't always a **shutdown** entry when I run `systemctl reboot` - I often see sequential **reboot** entries and user sessions are listed as **crash**. Sometimes however, we do get both shutdown and reboot entries logged.

Example where I ran `systemctl reboot` 4 times:

```
$ last -x reboot shutdown
reboot   system boot  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 13:12   still running
shutdown system down  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 13:12 - 13:12  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 12:56 - 13:12  (00:15)
reboot   system boot  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 11:24 - 13:12  (01:47)
reboot   system boot  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 11:23 - 13:12  (01:48)
shutdown system down  4.14.76-6.1.0-so Wed Aug 31 11:22 - 11:23  (00:00)
```

I have only found one question that directly addresses this but sadly [it is locked behind RHEL subscription](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5526311).

I am not dual-booting as per [this other SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465289/lubuntu-reboot-log-entries-don%c2%b4t-seem-to-be-correct), which may itself be an instance of inconsistent **shutdown** logging in wtmp.

Does anyone know why reboots via `systemctl` would not consistently log **shutdown** alongside **reboot**?

Is there a better way to reliably tell whether the system experienced unexpected reboots/power loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was [this bug ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1619994) where systemd unit dependencies were causing the utmp update service to not get run on shutdown.

By setting the `Requisite=` directive to blank for the `systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service` lastlog does now reliably gain **shutdown** entries on clean reboots.